# $(this) is not being recognized

Tags: jquery, textbox, format, this

I'm using the following to call a function, then format text within one or more textboxes that has the class "textprop". If I give the function variable a specific id for the textbox(i.e. $(#myid).val();) it works, but I can't get it to recognize "this". What am I doing wrong?

```
$(".textprop").keyup(function(){
    textProp();
});

function textProp() {
    var str = $('this').find('.textprop').val();
    str.val(str.replace(/\b\w+/g,function(s){return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substr(1).toLowerCase();}));
}
```

**UPDATE**

I thought this worked but I must have type capital inadvertently. The following is updated code but still does not work.

```
$(".textprop").keyup(function(){
    var str = $(this).find('.textprop').val();
    str.val(str.replace(/\b\w+/g,function(s){return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substr(1).toLowerCase();}));
});
```

**FINAL SOLUTION**

With Charlietfl help, here is the final solution...

```
$(".textprop").keyup(function(){
    var str = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(str.replace(/\b\w+/g,function(s){return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substr(1).toLowerCase();}));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to maintain context of `this` inside the function you would need to pass the function as reference instead of wrapping it it an anonymous function

```
$(".textprop").keyup(textProp);
```

An alternative would be to use javascript `bind()` to pass the context to the function

Note that `$('this')` should be `$(this)`

Comment: That worked! I was not clear about using anonymous functions with this. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I guess i spoke to soon as it does not seem to work. Did I do this right?

Comment: Change `$(this).find('.textprop').val();` to `$(this).val()` and `str.val()` should be `$(this).val(  str.replace(....`

Comment: Thanks Charlie for your time. That did it. Very much appreciated.